# Catch Python exception in CTypes callback

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a `ctypes` callback function like this:

```
def wrapper(ud, event):
    try:
        # ...
    except BaseException:
        wrapper.exc_info = sys.exc_info()
        return False

HandlerCallback = PYFUNCTYPE(c_int, py_object, Event)
cb = HandlerCallback(wrapper)
# pass `cb` to a C function

exc_info = getattr(wrapper, 'exc_info', None)
if exc_info:
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
```

Unfortunately that does not occupy 100% of the possible cases. Eg. I'm having trouble with a `KeyboardInteruppt` that seems to be raised between the C function invokation and the call to `wrapper()`. Unfortunately, the traceback is not helpfull at all.

Is it possible to make the `PYFUNCTYPE` wrapper catch any exception, NOT print them, and hand them back to me so I can reraise the exception after the C function call?

Comment: Is the callback called asynchronously on another thread? If that's the case there's no way it will ever see a `KeyboardInterrupt`. Python only runs signal handlers on its main thread. It has one C signal handling function that sets a flag if a signal is tripped. Then on the main thread it calls the handler, which may or may not raise an exception. For `SIGINT`, Python's `signal.default_int_handler` raises a `KeyboardInterrupt`.